# how to Know the longest ORF in Protein?

Tags: proteins, orf

I have a protein Seq. and I want to know

- how to Know the longest ORF in this Protein?

and if there is any tutorial for this process ??

Comment: Hi, you need to supply example data. The question has been asked and answered several times already and referring to past posts would help get you started.

Comment: If you have a protein sequence, you already have the ORF. I assume you mean you have a DNA sequence, not a protein sequence, right? In what species? Is there splicing? Is this a bacterium or a eukaryote? Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Add the actual sequence and the organism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proteins don't have ORFs, DNA sequences do.  What DNA sequences do you have?  If cDNA (i.e. transcript/mRNA) then an ORF finder will give multiple ORFs and the coordinates on the full-length input DNA which indicate it's length.

Comment: can you give me example of ORF finder.

Comment: EMBOSS has ORF finder, but it will find all ORFs, which may not be what you want (e.g. you may have to post-process to pick the longest of the overlapping ORFs).  Usually folks use a gene-finder instead, which includes an ORF finder but also other features, such as promoter/transcriptional start site and may include special handling for intron/exon boundaries (i.e. for eukaryotes).  I like Prodigal for microbiome data but there are several choices including genemark, fgenesh, glimmer/glimmerhmm, genscan although particular genefinders are usually suited for either prokaryotes or eukaryotes.